# await member.remove_roles(member, role)

Tags: discord.py, user-roles

I'm using discord.py rewrite.  I've been 3 days trying to get these two lines of code to work:

```
await member.remove_roles(tryMember, tryRole)
.
.
.
await member.add_roles(tryMember, tryRole)
```

here is the surrounding code including my troubleshoting comented out.  I have user ID# and role ID# to work with. This is a background process.

```
memberList = []
    for member in guild.members:

    ...
    ... decide on one of 3 roles for the user as proposedRole.   # role ID number
    ...

    for roleID in (serverSettings["inactive_r"], serverSettings["active_r"], serverSettings["very_active_r"]):
 
        if roleID != proposedRole:       
           try:
                print (roleID)
                tryRole = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.id == roleID, guild.roles)
                tryMember =  discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == member.id, guild.members)
                print (tryRole)    #only prints a member's name#number
                print (tryMember)  #only prints the role name

                await member.remove_roles(tryMember, tryRole)
                print (f'Removed {tryRole} from {tryMember} in {guild.name}')
            except Exception as e:
                print ('There was an error running this command: ' + str(e))

     ...  And repeat all this but adding the right role instead of removing the inocrrect roles
```

What gets printed out on the cosole per member is this:

```
709425978044186725      # the correct role ID
inactive                # the correct role name (I was expecting an object)
ArdenFutura#2469        # the correct member name (I was expecting an object)
There was an error running this command: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
                        # the e exception

664856898838855681      #aaaaand repeat...
active
ArdenFutura#2469
There was an error running this command: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
726974763649728593     
very active
ArdenFutura#2469
There was an error running this command: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

Ive been 3 days on these two lines of code. please help.

Comment: `await member.remove_roles(tryMember, tryRole)` this means you're trying to remove the roles `tryMember` and `tryRole` from `member`.  If you're trying to remove `tryRole` from `tryMember`, that would be `await tryMember.remove_roles(tryRole)`

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused with an [older version](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html?highlight=remove_roles#discord.Client.remove_roles) of the API Reference. `remove_roles` used to take two parameters:

`remove_roles(member, *roles)`

However, the [new documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=remove#discord.Member.remove_roles) states that only one parameter is required:

`remove_roles(*roles, reason=None, atomic=True)`

`roles` takes in a single role. If you wanted to remove multiple roles, a list of roles with an asterisk preceding the list would be passed in (`remove_roles(*[roleOne, roleTwo])`).
`reason` and `atomic` are optional parameters of type str and bool.

In your case, you are trying to remove `tryRole` from `tryMember`. The result would be:

`await tryMember.remove_roles(tryRole)`

Comment: hmmm...  yknow, I thought it was odd that I was using `member.` and specifying a member object again.  I'll try this when I get home.  Thank you both.